# vSphere Replication Guest OS Quiescing

Tags: replication, snapshot, vmware-vcenter, vss

I am using vSphere Replication 5.1 to send virtual machines to a separate datastore every 24 hours. One option in configuring each VMs replication is the Guest OS Quiescing option. Options are **None** and **MS Shadow Copy Services (VSS)**.

I not sure what the pros and cons of this option are and can't find much information explaining it. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: if the vm's are db's then quiesce using ms vss.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Do not use VSS with VR, If you use VVS some times (Consolidating disks) it makes VM not accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using [vSphere replication](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/replication) recently... There are only two options for guest [quiescing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce): [Microsoft VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) and none.

If your system being replicated supports quiescing, use it. Otherwise, you don't have any other options. Systems without a quiescing option become crash-consistent snapshots. But there are only *two* options offered, so please use what makes sense.

In my example below, all of the systems are Windows and support VSS, except for one, which is a Linux server, and has no quiescing option.

[image]

Easy enough?

Comment: I am currently using quiescing (MS VSS) option with vSphere Replication 5.1 and it really hang the system for a moment every time delta is send to recovery sitye. It is not good for the end users as if they are in middle of something server would not reponse and drop the request/data